# react router version 4 not showing anything

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, redux, react-router

I think that I am doing something wrong with my React router.  I am a beginner to React/Redux so any help is really appreciated.  It could also be how I configured webpack, but my front end is showing nothing, but I am not getting any errors at all.  I'm not sure what the problem is, but my server starts, is able to populate mock data, and webpack compiles, so I think the backend works.

I'm so sorry for the wall of code but I really have no idea where I'm going wrong and I am a huge newbie to setup on this.  This is definitely the longest post I've ever written so I appreciate anyone taking a look at it.

My client/src/routes:

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

import HomePage from './components/home/HomePage';  
import { Layout } from './components/Layout';  

export const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    </Switch>
  </Layout>
);

export default App;
```

client/src/Homepage.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="main">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
        <p>World</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default HomePage;
```

client/src/Layout.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Layout = props => (
  <div className="app-container">
    <header>
      <Link to="/">
      </Link>
    </header>
    <div className="app-content">{props.children}</div>
    <footer>
    </footer>
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

client/src/App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../store/Store';  
import { syncHistoryWithStore } from 'react-router-redux';
import routes from '../routes';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

const store = configureStore();

export default class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router routes={routes} />
        </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

client/src/index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import AppRoutes from './startup/App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <AppRoutes />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('main')
);
```

server/views/index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Buddie!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"><%- markup -%></div>
    <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

server/app.js:

```
/* eslint no-console: "off"*/

import path from 'path';
import { Server } from 'http';
import Express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { App } from '../client/src/startup/App';

const app = new Express();
const server = new Server(app);
const routes = require('../server/routes/index');

// use ejs templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

// define the folder that will be used for static assets
app.use(Express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));

app.use('/api/v1', routes)

// universal routing and rendering
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  let markup = '';
  let status = 200;

  if (process.env.UNIVERSAL) {
    const context = {};
    markup = renderToString(
      <Router location={req.url} context={context}>
        <App />
      </Router>,
    );

    // context.url will contain the URL to redirect to if a <Redirect> was used
    if (context.url) {
      return res.redirect(302, context.url);
    }

    if (context.is404) {
      status = 404;
    }
  }

  return res.status(status).render('index', { markup });
});

// start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';
server.listen(port, (err) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.error(err);
  }
  return console.info(
    `
      Server running on http://localhost:${port} [${env}]
      Universal rendering: ${process.env.UNIVERSAL ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}
    `);
});
```

webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: './client/src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'server', 'static', 'js'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [ 'babel-loader' ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: 'body',
      filename: 'index.html'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development')
    })
  ]
};
```

package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run build:dev && babel-node server/app.js",
    "start:dev": "export NODE_ENV=development && npm run build:dev && nodemon --exec babel-node -- src/server.js",
    "start:universal": "export UNIVERSAL=true && npm run start",
    "start:dev:universal": "export NODE_ENV=development && export UNIVERSAL=true && npm run start:dev",
    "build": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p",
    "build:dev": "webpack -d",
    "build:dev:watch": "webpack -d --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-node6": "^11.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "chalk": "^1.1.3",
    "classnames": "^2.2.5",
    "concurrently": "^3.4.0",
    "debug": "^2.6.8",
    "ejs": "^2.5.6",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "immutable": "^3.8.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "morgan": "^1.8.2",
    "node-jsx": "^0.13.3",
    "nodemon": "^1.11.0",
    "normalizr": "^3.2.3",
    "pg": "^6.2.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "15.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^1.0.7",
    "react-slick": "^0.14.11",
    "redux": "^3.7.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "sequelize": "^4.1.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^2.7.0",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.5",
    "yargs": "^8.0.2"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8000"
```

Comment: Could you try to `render() { return <div> test </div>}` on the App? This will help pinpoint if it's an issue with the server-side render or the router

Comment: Will do when I get home, will report back @grandas, thanks!

Comment: @Grandas I did that and the page displays "test" so I think it is a router/frontend problem if I'm not mistaken?

Answer (score 1):

In your `src/client/App.js` file, I noticed you're importing syncHistoryWithStore from react-router-redux. I'm fairly confident RR4 and the old version of react-router-redux are not compatible with one another. The new version installed with @next does not contain syncHistoryWithStore.

This might be your issue.

Comment: I am adding my package.json dependencies, I think its right I think that was just old code

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed something in this code block

```
if (process.env.UNIVERSAL) {
const context = {};
markup = renderToString(
  <Router location={req.url} context={context}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
);

// context.url will contain the URL to redirect to if a <Redirect> was used
if (context.url) {
  return res.redirect(302, context.url);
}

if (context.is404) {
  status = 404;
}
```

}

You are assigning an empty object to `context`, passing an empty context to your`<Router />`and then checking for `context.url` and `context.is404`, which are both going to be `undefined`everytime you check them! Maybe you meant `context = {...context}` ? Really unsure whether this affects rendering (pretty sure it does not) but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: thank you, i changed it but i havent been running this code as universal usually so it hasnt been the culprit.  Thanks for the advice though checking it out now!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not running this code as universal, then it will never update the markup and it will always be empty hence will not print anything.

One small correction in your code: in index.ejs

> remove last '-' in markup tag it should be <%- markup %>